# Get the values of the second select from the options of the first select in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, html-select

Hail. I'm trying to make a second select options from the first select options using the http://fipeapi.appspot.com/ api.

E.g. In the first select I have the following options:
1.Fruits
2.Roots
3.Flowers

If I choose Fruits will appear Orange, Apple and Strawberry
If I choose Roots will appear Beet, Carrot and Radish
If I choose Flowers will appear Artichoke, Cauli-flower and Broccoli

So when I choose the Fruits I don't get the value of first selection to show the options of the second selection

I tried make a ref to take the value of the first selection but I don't get use it in the second selection.

All code:
http://jsfiddle.net/Orcrinhos/jfq7zc5p/

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import './App.css';

class App extends Component {
  constructor() {
    super();

    this.state = {
      marks: [],
      models: [],
    };

    this.handleSubmit = this.handleSubmit.bind(this);
    this.getMark = this.getMark.bind(this);
    this.getModel = this.getModel.bind(this);
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    this.getMarkInfo();
    this.getModelInfo();
  }

  handleSubmit(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    alert('test');
  }

  getMark(event) {
    this.getMarkInfo(this.refs.markRef.value)
    this.setState({ markValue: event.target.value });
  }

  getModel(event) {
    this.getCarInfo(this.refs.modelRef.value)
    this.setState({ modelValue: event.target.value });
  }

  getMarkInfo() {
    const url = `http://fipeapi.appspot.com/api/1/carros/marcas.json`;
    fetch(url)
      .then(data => data.json())
      .then(data => this.setState({ marks: data }));
  }

  getModelInfo(markRef = this.refs.markRef.value) {
    const url = `http://fipeapi.appspot.com/api/1/carros/veiculos/${markRef}.json`;

    fetch(url)
      .then(data => data.json())
      .then(data => this.setState({ models: data }));
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <form>
          <fieldset>
            <legend>Some legend</legend>

            {/* First select */}
            <select ref="markRef" onChange={(e) => { this.getMark(); }}>
              {this.state.marks.map(function (mark, index) {
                return (
                  <option key={index} value={mark.id}>{mark.name}</option>
                )
              }
              )}
            </select>

            {/* Second select */}
            <select ref="modelRef" onChange={(e) => { this.getModel(); }}>
              {this.state.models.map(function (model, index) {
                return (
                  <option key={index} value={model.id}>{model.name}</option>
                )
              }
              )}
            </select>
          </fieldset>

          <button type="submit">Show data</button>
        </form>

        <h3>Marks of car</h3>
        <div className="break">
          {this.state.marks.map(function (mark, index) {
            return (
              <div key={index}>
                <p>{mark.name}</p>
              </div>
            )
          }
          )}
        </div>

        <h3>Models of car</h3>
        {this.state.models.map(function (model, index) {
          return (
            <div key={index}>
              <p>{model.name}</p>
            </div>
          )
        }
        )}

      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

When I'm trying others ways appear:

*Cannot read property 'target' of undefined*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please pass event as argument in function. Try below

```
 {/* First select */}
            <select ref="markRef" onChange={(e) => { this.getMark(e); }}> // pass event as e
              {this.state.marks.map(function (mark, index) {
                return (
                  <option key={index} value={mark.id}>{mark.name}</option>
                )
              }
              )}
            </select>

            {/* Second select */}
            <select ref="modelRef" onChange={(e) => { this.getModel(e); }}> //pass e
              {this.state.models.map(function (model, index) {
                return (
                  <option key={index} value={model.id}>{model.name}</option>
                )
              }
              )}
            </select>
```

Comment: Thank you ravi, but now the url appear this way:
http://fipeapi.appspot.com/api/1/carros/veiculos/.json

without the number of the ref. :/

Comment: Use 
const url = `http://fipeapi.appspot.com/api/1/carros/veiculos/${this.state.markValue}.json`;